# C++ Improve time complexity

Tags: c++, time

I would like to ask for tips on how to improve the time complexity of the program.
I can't change the interface (function headers)

For example, if I do sort before find (), will it have any effect?
Or are there any alternatives to my code.

Thank you for all the advice

In the link to the whole program, here is a part of the code
https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3xxpa4w9q

```
bool Company::operator == (Company cmpx)  const
{ 

    return ( ( (strcasecmp(addr.c_str(), cmpx.addr.c_str()) == 0) 
            && (strcasecmp(name.c_str(), cmpx.name.c_str()) == 0) )
            || (id == cmpx.id)
    );
    
}

void CVATRegister::sortI (vector<unsigned int> &TotalInvoice) const 
{
    sort(TotalInvoice.begin(), TotalInvoice.end(), greater<unsigned int>());
}

bool CVATRegister::cancelCompany  ( const string  &name, const string &addr )
{
    Company cmp(name, addr, "-1");
    auto itr = find(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp);

    if(itr != DCompany.end())
     {   
        DCompany.erase(itr);
        return true;
     }
     
     return false;
}

bool CVATRegister::newCompany ( const string &name, const string &addr, const string &taxID )
{
    Company cmp(name, addr, taxID);
    if ( find(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp) == DCompany.end() )
    {
        DCompany.push_back(cmp);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool CVATRegister::invoice ( const string &taxID, unsigned int amount )
{
    Company cmp("", "", taxID);

    auto itr = find(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp);

    if(itr != DCompany.end())
     {   
        TotalInvoice.push_back(amount);
        DCompany[distance(DCompany.begin(), itr)].saveInvoice(amount);
        return true;
     }
     
     return false;    
}

bool CVATRegister::audit ( const string &name, const string  &addr, unsigned int &sumIncome ) const
{
    Company cmp(name, addr,"-1");

    auto itr = find(DCompany.begin(), DCompany.end(), cmp);

    if(itr != DCompany.end())
     {   
        sumIncome = DCompany[distance(DCompany.begin(), itr)].getTotalIncome();
        return true;
     }
     return false;
}

void CVATRegister::sortC (vector<Company> &c) const
{
   sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}


bool CVATRegister::firstCompany ( string &name, string &addr ) const
{
    vector<Company> tmp = DCompany;
    sortC(tmp);

    if( tmp.size() > 0 )
    {   
        name = tmp[0].getName();
        addr = tmp[0].getAddr();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you have a vector and pre-sort it, you can use a [std::binary_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search).

Comment: Better if you focus on the time complexity of functions. From the complexity of the functions you can determine the complexity of functions that call those functions and ultimately the whole program, if time complexity makes sense for the program. Often it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorting to get min/max in `firstCompany` is not necessary, just find the min/max with a for loop or `max_element`.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is profile your code, there's no point optimising the fast parts of your program when there are other parts which are much slower. You need to find the slow parts then you can ask a more focused question on how to speed up those specific parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing companies in a vector. In multiple methods, the vector is sorted and the searched.

- do not sort the vector again if it is already sorted
- as pointed out, use a binary search instead of std::find
- or use a hash-based container, e.g. std::unordered_set to store the companies. This should make most operations O(1) on average.
- or use multiple containers, accessing/updating each as needed
- or write your own :)